# Sort query result rows by index?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table in my database for my website news, but I'd like to sort the news by an index, descending.
For example, I have 3 rows, each with diiferent indexes: 1, 2 and 3. I want to sort my rows descending by the index and display them in this order: 3, 2 and 1.

Here is some code to start with...

```
<?php
ob_start();

$host="hosty";
$username="usey";
$password="passy";
$db_name="namey";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tabley`';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result)
{
    die(mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo 'row...';
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tabley` order by id DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `tabley` ORDER BY index DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have an index called `id` for instance.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tabley` ORDER BY `id` DESC';
```

`DESC` stands for descending, `ORDER BY` is SQL terminology for sort.

Comment: heh. I think people people knew how to do this one.